# angular 4 ngModule inject provider/services conditionally

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [MyService,
          // providers used to create fake backend
          fakeBackendProvider,
          MockBackend,
          BaseRequestOptions
         ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

fakeBackendProvider, MockBackend and BaseRequestOptions are for the mock up back end. Is there way to inject these services by a variable in environment.ts file?

Comment: I'd suggest a factory provider: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#usefactorythe-factory-provider

Comment: You can create own service which will provide proper instance of service with proper interface depending on env flag. You can see [my repo](https://github.com/ArturCzopek/my-coach/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/service.injector.ts). Maybe you'll see there some inspiration ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this. Created [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUb144JFnRthKhnhd4Rj?p=preview)

```
//route to environment file
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
providers: [MyService,
          // providers used to create fake backend
     {
      provide: SomeSerivce,
      useFactory: authHeadersFactory
    },       
   ],


export function authHeadersFactory() {
  if (environment.prod) {
    return new Mock();
  }
  return new fakeBackend();
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But when I run `npm start` for development it keep throw this error. ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Can You share the code cause its copy paste from my project where i use it and it works fine.

Comment: @etlds create plunker

Comment: Sorry, I decided to use ant to comment out these three lines of code before the build. I will create a Plunker later. But the difference between my problem and your Plunker is MockBackend and BaseRequestOptions are from 'angular/http/testing' and 'angular/http'. They are not the Injectable class that I own.